# Detect online presence using cloud functions

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I am creating an online game using flutter and cloudfirestore, my main problem is detecting the online status of the user since the game is online.

I know that cloudfirestore does not support detecting presence natively and we can use realtime database combined with cloudfire store to detect presence but I want to create a way to detect presence using cloudfunctions and cloudfirestore only. Is this possible? Please provide me with some archticture to follow.

Comment: Adding Cloud Functions to Cloud Firestore won't make it any more possible.  The issue is that the Cloud Firestore SDK simply doesn't expose the state of the connection that it hold to the server, and it doesn't necessarily attempt to keep that connection open all the time.

Comment: The only thing I believe could work is for you to make use of the application life circle. Example you could update users online present each time the disposes life circle is called and update status each time the app class is initiated.. That on disposes (user goes offline)  on initiated (users goes online again )

Comment: Since your are using fire store and the app in connected to the internet it will all work out fine BUT I mush let you know that this is not a good practice

Comment: I have searched a lot but it looks like currently the only way is to dual connect databases, so I came with an idea which is keeping the state of the game as in the database and keep all the players waiting for the offline player to come back and continue his move but the game will not display that the user is offline

Comment: @ikben another solution is that to set a timer for 60s that is triggered in cloud functions for each player, if the player does not perform any update in the database within the 60s the cloud function will change his status to offline, but this will contain a lot of work and logic to implement.

Comment: @maria Mad  it will lot of money on clouds functions because in a day your have a lot of innovations and also you function will have to loop over all your users this might become more expensive at a later time. Imaging your gave 5 million user and 1 million active users